# Combinations of 6 students among 20, at least one male

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following problem: A class has 20 students, 16 females, 4 males. Find all possibilities of choosing 6 students so that at least one is male.

I did the following, pick one male from the 4, you have 4 possibilities, then you are left with 19 students, pick 5, so I get 4*${19}\choose{5}$ possibilities.

However, one can notice that if you want no one to be male, then the possibilities are ${16}\choose{6}$, so, one could argue that the solution is instead ${20}\choose{6}$ - ${16}\choose{6}$.

So, which is solution is correct, and why?

$$4* {{19}\choose{5}}$$ 
or
$${{20}\choose{6}} - {{16}\choose{6}}$$

Comment: The second solution is correct.  The first overcounts several scenarios where the male picked in step one is instead picked during step two.  One could also solve this by cases where you count the number of combinations with *exactly* one male, *exactly* two males, ..., *exactly* six males, and then add together.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your answer, but why? I pick a male in step one, then I remove him from the class, I am left with 19 students (16 female and 3 male), so I pick another 5. The question says at least one male. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's funny, I made the exact same mistake recently. The problem with the first approach is that it contains double counting.

Say you start out by picking male $A$ among the four males $A, B, C, D$, and then you choose $5$ people among the remaining $19$. Maybe one of these five people is male $B$, and the rest are $x, y, z, w$.

But you could also originally have picked male $B$, and then male $A$ could have been among the $5$ people that you then choose out of $19$, where the rest are also $x, y, z, w$. It's the same choice as before.

The second solution is correct.

Comment: Why did the fundamental principle of counting fail here though? I normally have the habit of making a statement with ANDs and ORs and then writiting it down mathematically. It has pretty much always worked for me before

Comment: @Dèsjardins I suppose it is because the objects are interchangable. It's like if you have a group of $5$ types of paint, and another group of $4$ types of material for a wall, and you want the number of ways of choosing one paint type and one material type, then you get $5\cdot 4$ (one type of paint AND one type of material). If on the other hand, you have $5$ types of fruit, and you want to choose $2$, then you can't say "first one fruit AND then a second fruit", giving $5\cdot 4$. The real answer is of course $\binom{5}{2}$, which is $(5\cdot 4)/2$, with the reason being interchangeability.

Comment: Aah yes that makes sense. is there a formal proof or rule for such things though? Thanks for taking the time to explain it btw

Comment: @Dèsjardins I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The first problem asks for the number of elements in the product set $\{\text{paint 1},\text{paint 2},\text{paint 3},\text{paint 4},\text{paint 5}\}\times \{\text{wall 1},\text{wall 2},\text{wall 3},\text{wall 4}\}$, and the product set $A\times B$ always has $|A|\cdot |B|$ elements. The second asks for the number of maps from some two-element set $\{0,1\}$ to $\{\text{fruit 1},\text{fruit 2},\text{fruit 3},\text{fruit 4},\text{fruit 5}\}$, but modulo the relation that functions with the same image are equal.